# I formatted my Seagate hard disk using Ubuntu and now I am unable to see it in files

Tags: 18.04

I am a new Ubuntu 18.04 user. I formatted my hard disk using Ubuntu and now it is not showing. Though whenever I connect it, that click sounds comes (the same sound whenever I connect any pen drive or mouse).

Comment: can you see it in "Disks" ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the disk doesn't contain any recognizable partitions. If that's the case, you should be able to use the fdisk command to remove any unrecognizable partitions and create a new (good) one. Hope that's helpful!